# How to provide configurable scripts with PHP composer

Tags: php, configuration, composer-php

I want to provide a script that can be installed with PHP's package manager `composer` and that must be configurable.

With composer, we can easily define [vendor binaries](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/vendor-binaries.md).

However, I don't see any possibility to configure them.

One could include a configuration file from within the package. However, name and location of the vendor directory are configurable, so this will not be very reliable.

For comparison: With Python's package manager `pip`, we can use environment variables for the configuration. We can set the environment variables while activating the virtual environment, e.g. by using tools like the `virtualenvwrapper`.

There must be at least experiments with similar approaches in the PHP community.

**Addendum: The story behind**

I have scripts that synchronize the databases and user generated files for test versions of websites.

For *Django* sites, I'm always using the same scripts, they rely on environment variables that I define with the virtualenvwrapper.

For *Drupal* sites, one can achieve a lot with drush.

But for *Wordpress*, I cannot find a simple and clean tool. It should

- live outside the folders available to the public
- be installable with composer, eventually in combination with other general-purpose-PHP-tools
- use a simple and robust way to detect the settings.

To be honest, I'm missing the *virtualenvwrapper* in PHP.
The virtualenvwrapper is a linux script that basically does two things:

1. It activates a Python virtualenvironment. Translated to PHP that would mean that everything that follows uses the autoloader of a certain composer package.
2. It executes a script when activating or deactivating the virtualenvironment. There, one has the possibility to define environment variables a do any other useful things.

Comment: Usually PHP libraries don't try to directly load configurations, but instead take config parameters when classes are instantiated.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I follow what you're trying to achieve here. What's the script being used for? Are you using different versions and you want to provide a specific one for a specific case? Have you thought of using `Symfony Console` instead of your script? You can easily pass arguments when executing the console commands which can trigger different behaviors.

Comment: I think you're trying to break the point of composer there, the whole point is that your code is set up so the user's app using your library can configure it so you should set up a Configuration system most people do this by creating a interface that gets extended and passed to your class on obj initialization

Comment: I've added some text to my question where I explain the motivation behind it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, but there are plenty of options if you want to use env vars in Php.

https://github.com/symfony/dotenv is one of them and well maintained.

```
<?php
use Symfony\Component\Dotenv\Dotenv;

$dotenv = new Dotenv();
$dotenv->load(__DIR__.'/path/to/.env');
```

Then you can use those env var the way you want for configuration purposes. E.g. for DB config:

```
$someSettings = [
    // Db config
    DB_CONNECTION => [
        'host' => getenv('DB_HOST'),
        'username' => getenv('DB_USERNAME'),
        'password' => getenv('DB_PASSWORD'),
        'database' => getenv('DB_DATABASE')
    ]
];
```

Comment: I'll place the `.env` file in the root folder of my project. In the installable script, I'll search all parent folders for `.env` files and use the first one that I can find.

Answer (score 3):

You can add a [post-package-install](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md#installer-events) script.  With that you can use something like symfony/console to allow the installer to do some sort of configuration.

Answer (score 2):

With a composer you can do something like that (PATH is your environment variable):

```
{
    "name": "test/test",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Test",
            "email": "test@email.com"
        }
    ],
    "require": {

    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@echoPath"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@echoPath"
        ],
        "echoPath": "echo $PATH"
    }
}
```

Not sure if this is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

As other users, I'm unsure what your end goal is here but what you have seemed to have outlined appears to break the point of using composer the whole point of the composer is that the code works with any application & required dependencies are obtained on install.

For What your trying to do of creating a setup for "configuration setting" are normally implemented by setting up a configuration interface that the using App has to create and provide for your class / created objects to initialize.

For example, your composer lib requires a login system now it could well be the app it's being used /installed in to already has a login system. No developer ever want two different login tables for a single app in their Database so you should create an interface that developers app can implement and provide the configuration that is needed

Code Example:

Example class to do something (your library entry class)

```
<?php
namespace my_namespace;

class DoSomething{
    private $config;

    public function __construct(\my_namespace\interface\Config $config)
    {
        $this->config = $config;
    }

    function doLogin()
    {
        // get $username and $password
        $state = $this->config->CheckUserLogin($username, $password);
        if(!is_bool($state)){ throw new Exception("State of CheckUserLogin from class '".get_class($this->config)."' is incorrect expected boolean but '".gettype($state)."' was provided"); }
    }

}
```

Example Config Interface: (your composer's library config interface)

```
<?php
namespace my_namespace\interface;

interface Config{

    public function CheckUserLogin($username, $password);

    //....

}
```

This means i could install your Library via composer and setup like so.

Example my app Config for your library: (the class the using app has to build inheriting your interface)

```
<?php
namespace myapp;

class DoSomethingConfig implementes \my_namespace\interface\Config{
    public function CheckUserLogin($username, $password)
    {
        // do my login system ($loginState)
        return $loginState;
    }
}
```

Example my initializing of your library: (the code any app would have to use)

```
<?php
namespace myapp;

class ConnectToSomething{
    private $lib;

    public function __construct(){
        $config = new \myapp\DoSomethingConfig();
        $this->lib = new \my_namespace\DoSomething($config);
    }

}
```

This way you give developer free reign to work with your code base. while they should never be wanting to edit your classes because you have done something that would cause duplicate information.

This is a simple example that highlights the point I'm trying to make don't try to run a config script to get the users to setup stuff for your library make them set up the stuff that needed in a way where they can then manage that connection point between your code and there's, this also provides security as they know your not accessing information you should not be and send it to your servers.

As they provide your code with the access it requires to work and nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

I think, what are you looking for is probably something like a library https://packagist.org/packages/hiqdev/composer-config-plugin

It is a quite popular library and managed also by a creator/contributor of the Yii/2 framework Samdark https://packagist.org/users/samdark/
or the creator of the asset-packagist hiqdev
https://packagist.org/users/hiqdev/

`This Composer plugin provides assembling of configurations distributed with composer packages. It allows putting configuration needed to use a package right inside of the package thus implementing a plugin system. The package becomes a plugin holding both the code and its configuration.`

**Usage:**

```
"extra": {
    "config-plugin-output-dir": "path/relative-to-composer-json",
    "config-plugin": {
        "params": [
            "config/params.php",
            "?config/params-local.php"
        ],
        "common": "config/common.php",
        "web": [
            "$common",
            "config/web.php"
        ],
        "other": "config/other.php"
    }
},
```